# Ipad two ImagePickers for one view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two image pickers in one view on my ipad application. One opens the photo library as a popover and the other shows the camera, and allows the user to take a picture and save it  to the same UIImage as the photo libary.

I can't use didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo twice, so I've added an if then statement based on the source type as a workaround. This approach results in an error "Expected ']' on the "if ([picker....line "

Any help on how to solve this error would be appreciated.

```
#pragma mark Camera/Library

//Button to open library
- (IBAction)library:(id)sender{

    //Create image picker controller

   self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    //Set source to the photo library
   self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
   self. imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   self.imagePicker.allowsEditing  = NO;

    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                       initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
   self.popoverController.delegate = self;
   CGRect popoverRect  = [self.view convertRect:[self.view frame]
                                       fromView:[self.view superview]];

   popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 80) ;
   popoverRect.origin.x = popoverRect.origin.x+150;

    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}


-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.popoverController != nil) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:animated];
        self.popoverController  = nil;
    }
}


- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    self.popoverController=nil;
}


- (IBAction)camera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
     //Create image picker controller

   self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

   self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
   self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   self.imagePicker.allowsEditing  = NO;

    self.imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    { 
   UIAlertView *alert  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera failed to open"
         message:@"Camera is not available" delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
         otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

#pragma mark Image Picker Delegate Methods

//on cancel dimiss picker controller
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

//Used when user has chosen an image
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    if ([picker sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        imageView.image = image;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
   UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   imageView.image  = image;
    }   
 }
```

Comment: `if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)` write this

Comment: I still get the expected ']' as well as expected expression in the next line and use of undeclared identifier in the following line

Comment: i copy your code to my xcode and just replace that line and it is working fine for me

Comment: are you getting undeclared identifier for imageView??

Comment: actually I just fixed that error but I still get the other ones

Answer (score 0):

You should follow below logic. This is worked for you, try it once. Names the buttons like libraryButton , cameraButton and Provide Same  ButtonAction for both buttons.

In View Controller .h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *libraryButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cameraButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;

@end
```

and View Controller .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize libraryButton;
@synthesize cameraButton;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender{
    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sender == libraryButton) {
        printf("\n library button calling");
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else if (sender == cameraButton) {
         printf("\n camera button calling");
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
            self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self.imagePickerController setAllowsEditing:YES];
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else{
            UIAlertView *alert  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera failed to open" message:@"Camera is not available" delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    picker = nil;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0);
    self.image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    self.myImageView.image = self.image1;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: So I map one button to Button Action, and from there how do let it know library and camera button done? currently I get a use of undeclared identifier 'librarybutton'

Comment: you have 2 buttons right, then named libraryButton for first button and named cameraButton for second button . In ButtonAction  , sender ==libraryButton and sender==cameraButton will take care your choice.

Comment: Yes that is correct, so I am still getting the use of undeclared identifier for both buttons, any ideas on why that is? also this is exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: .h file you have to declare  IBOutlet UIButton * labraryButton; IBOutlet UIButton * cameraButton; and finally connect this two buttons in your .Xib or Storyboard file.

Comment: Thank you! that worked, I don't have to map ButtonAction correct?

Comment: not exactly, do i have to map buttonaction to a new button in my view controller? and apart from saving I also want to display the selected/ or taken picture in an image view

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: I get an unrecognized selector sent to instance for libraryButton which then crashes. The camera button doesn't do anything when pressed

Comment: oh god .... i think you are not connect your button names in storyboard. please check it once

Comment: Double checked and I do have them connected

Comment: abdiel.ramirez01@gmail.com